# Rendered animation cropped in unintended way

Tags: rendering

I am relatively new to blender, and have done only a several renders.

The following link takes you to my insta post with the video. I did select render region to speed up the render time, but as you can see, certain areas disappear or gets cropped as the camera moves.

https://www.instagram.com/tv/CboDKg2Bc2p/?utm_medium=copy_link

Is there any solution to this? Even a wild guess would mean a lot to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you checked the camera or scene clipping values?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I might have tweaked the settings without knowing what I'm doing along the way. I will look it up. Thanks again.

Comment: Check the N panel > View > View > Clip Start and Clip End, and also select the camera and in the Camera panel > Lens > Clip Start and Clip End. I'm not sure this is your problem though...

Comment: It does look like an end clipping issue, but the clipping settings to change for final render are on the camera, panel Lens, make the clip End bigger and leave clip Start as it is.

Comment: It seems the Clip End was set to 100m, and apparently my scene was larger than that. There is no way I could figure it out without asking you guys. Thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Check the *N panel > View > View > Clip Start* and *Clip End*, and also select the camera and in the *Camera panel > Lens > Clip Start* and *Clip End*.